# How can i send html content in my email,using perl

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl.

Iam using following perl code for sending mail.

And its working fine.

But how can i include html content in it?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP ();
use Email::Simple ();
use Email::Simple::Creator ();

my $smtpserver = 'xxxx.xx.x.x.';
my $smtpport = 25;
my $smtpuser   = 'test@test.com';
my $smtppassword = 'xxxxx';

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
  host => $smtpserver,
  port => $smtpport,
  sasl_username => $smtpuser,
  sasl_password => $smtppassword,
});

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
    To      => 'xxx@xxxx.com',
    From    => 'test@test.com',
    Subject => 'Hi!'

  ],
  body => "<table><tr><td>try</td></tr></table>",
);

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
print "Success \n";
1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The joy of using modules from the Email::* namespace is that they all work together nicely. Currently you're using Email::Simple to create the email and Email::Sender to send it. But now you no longer want to create simple email, you want to create more complex ones. The format for sending complex email like this is [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME). So you should look for something in the Email::MIME namespace that you can plug in in place of Email::Simple. [Email::MIME::CreateHTML](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aMIME%3a%3aCreateHTML) looks like it's exactly what you want.

From the Synopsis:

```
use Email::MIME::CreateHTML;
my $email = Email::MIME->create_html(
        header => [
                From => 'my@address',
                To => 'your@address',
                Subject => 'Here is the information you requested',
        ],
        body => $html,
        text_body => $plain_text
);

use Email::Send;
my $sender = Email::Send->new({mailer => 'SMTP'});
$sender->mailer_args([Host => 'smtp.example.com']);
$sender->send($email);
```

It looks like this would be simple enough to convert to your usage.

Comment: Thanks Dave.Its works Fine.Let me know, what is the use of text_body => $plain_text  ?

Comment: The `text_body` parameter is explained in the documentation for the module - "A scalar value holding the contents of an additional plain text message body." When sending HTML email you should always send a plan text version of the same content as well. You do that using the `text_body` parameter.

Comment: @Dave.Iam using sendmail($email, { transport => $transport }); for sending mail.
How can i get the response code for success or error message in case failure

Comment: Reading the documentation for Email::Sender::Simple (https://metacpan.org/module/Email::Sender::Simple) directs you do Email::Sender::Manual::Quickstart (https://metacpan.org/module/Email::Sender::Manual::QuickStart) which seems to answer that question pretty thoroughly. Did reading the documentation go out of fashion or something?

Comment: I tried the following code, think its working.

eval {
sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });    # this is try catch method
};
if ($@) {
  # where $@ is a object of Email::Sender::Failure
 print $@->message;
 print"\n".$@->code ;
   # print  "Oh no!". $@->what;
}else{
 print "success";
}

Comment: Putting code in comments on StackOverflow is generally a terrible idea. If you have a separate question (as this was) then you're far better off starting a new discussion.